# Puttin loop output to new object in r

Tags: r, loops, output

I've created a for loop using r. This loop iterates m (m = 1128) times. Inside each of this iterations there is another loop which results in a object with 60 values. I want to read these 60 values into a new object as a row.

The dots below are just functions applied to get me to the object AGC

```
for (m in 1:1128){
.
.
.  
AGC <- t(Mean - 273.15)  #Object with 60 values
Annual <- matrix(NA,1128,60)  
Annual[m,] <- AGC
}
```

The values are not saving to Annual. i.e the values for m=1 are stored in Annual[1,] but for the next iteration m=2, the values in Annual[1,] disappears.

Comment: Why do you need to take the transpose?  You could assign it directly, rigth?

Comment: You are writing over `Annual` with each run in line 6

Comment: Initialize a `list` before the inner loop. Append the results of the inner loop to that list. Concatenate the results using `unlist` and assign

Comment: As Pierre Lafortune tells, to be more explicit, you must pre-assign `Annual` before entering the loop: put `Annual <- matrix(NA,1128,60)` before the `for` and that will work.